# Asihttprequest localizedDescription always in English

Tags: ios, localization, asihttprequest

im using Asihttprequest for my HTTP request, and my app will handel 3 language : arabic, french and english but Asihttprequest error localizedDescription return always an english description.
is Asihttprequest request use the default ios systeme localisation description? if yes how can i localize error ?
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of what exactly you asked for, but you can try this.

In the ASIHttpRequest.m file `Initialize` method use `NSLocalizedString(@"REQUESTTIMEOUT_KEY", @"The request timed out")` instead of `@"The request timed out"`.

Have the `"REQUESTTIMEOUT_KEY" = "EngVersion:The request timed out";` in the corresponding localizable.strings file.

Sample Code:

```
ASIRequestTimedOutError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:NetworkRequestErrorDomain code:ASIRequestTimedOutErrorType userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSLocalizedString(@"REQUESTTIMEOUT_KEY", @"The request timed out"),NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,nil]];
```

Comment: thank you for replaying, i was thinking that ASIHttpRequest have a localized error message, but you solution is great an easy to use, thank you .