# Accessing localized error message from ASIHTTPrequest calls

Tags: localization, asihttprequest, nserror

I'm using the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to perform some HTTP calls.  In a certain case when the network isn't available, I display a dialog with the error from the `NSError` object returned.  My problem occurs when I change my language settings (to Spanish).  The `localizedDescription` always returns in English:

```
NSLog(@"userInfo: %@", [error userInfo]);
NSLog(@"localizedDescription: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

prints:

```
2012-04-05 22:02:05.519 MyApp[18644:207] userInfo: {
NSLocalizedDescription = "A connection failure occurred";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. Conexi\U00f3n rechazada\" UserInfo=0x594f880 {}";
}
2012-04-05 22:02:05.519 MyApp[18644:207] localizedDescription: A connection failure occurred
```

`localizedDescription` is still in English, but inside `[error userInfo]`, in the `NSUnderlyingError`, there is a Spanish translation available, but I don't know how to access it via the `NSError` object returned.

A similar question was [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354353/asihttprequest-localizeddescription-always-in-english) asked, but the answer is not satisfactory and not scalable for all possible error messages.

Comment: I was able to find a solution, although awkward: `[[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSUnderlyingError"] localizedFailureReason]`.  I will leave this question open for a couple days to see if anyone can provide a better answer.

Comment: Did you find the reason for the original issue?